# How to display string on LCD of intel Edison Board

Tags: string, intel, display, lcd, intel-edison

As the title suggests. Let's say I have a string in my c code like "hello world". I want to display this message to my intel Edison board LCD display. How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Edit: the LCD screen is from a grove kit so i.e.: reading temperature with the temp sensor would require the API of mraa

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you look? Do you want purely software help or do you need hardware help as well? What IDE are you using? Is your C code on the Edison already? Or is it on your computer?Did you google this yet? I assume you are using the jhd1313m1 from the grove kit? I found this code google: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/upm/blob/master/examples/c/jhd1313m1.c

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far. I am completely at a loss of how to do it. Anyway, I do want mostly software help but any hardware help is much appreciated. I am coding directly on the edison in C, with vi. And yes, the jhd1313m1 is the LCD i'm using from my grove kit. I will tinker with your link and see if it helps. Any other advice is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, there are drivers and frameworks, but there is no clean support in upstream kernel. I would highly **not** recommend to use UPM or MRAA user space libraries. They do nasty things.

Comment: I have to use mraa since it is required to read temperature ratings from the temp sensor. Other than that, where can i find these drivers/frameworks?

Comment: Where do i get the libraries though that the xample used @Whitney because when i tried compiling it didn't like "jhd1313m1.h" and "upm_utilities.h"